# Change integrated security user of Content Manager

Tags: web8

I installed Content Manager Server (SDL Web 8) with the Integrated Security database setting. I ran the installer under a user that had rights on the database. How can I change the user that was used when running the installer?

Comment: What database are you using? Oracle, SQL, RDS...?

Comment: Good one :), I am using MSSQL

Comment: Did you try the following? http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Web-v1&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-A5AF3E59-2D5B-4CE2-B86C-91A9CE1CB37F&addHistory=true&query=integrated&scope=&tid=f3ad4f5b-9a2b-43f2-b9e0-458573622083&filename=GUID-A5AF3E59-2D5B-4CE2-B86C-91A9CE1CB37F.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-A5AF3E59-2D5B-4CE2-B86C-91A9CE1CB37F&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL+Web-v1%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3Dintegrated&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1450798951474&currentQuery=integrated&currentScope=

Comment: I have seen that. Are you saying that the content manager does not run under the user used to run the installer, but always under `<DOMAIN>\<MACHINE>$`?

Comment: Honestly, I have not tried it (since it was officially not supported in 2013 :-)) but it would help if you edit your question to include the recommended steps from the documentation and re-post any warnings or messages that surface. Hence, leaving comments vs. answers...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you configure CM to use Windows Integrated security to connect to MSSQL, it won't connect as the user who ran the installer, but with the identity of the CM Kernel host processes.

Typically, that means NETWORK SERVICE (TcmServiceHost.exe, TcmBatchProcessor.exe) and SYSTEM (TcmPublisher.exe)
Note that these identities are represented as the computer account (DOMAIN\COMPUTERNAME$) when accessing network resources.

So,indeed, you should configure MSSQL to allow logins from computer accounts from all CM servers.

Comment: Or alternatively, use domain accounts.